# Rails group collection and sum certain fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

New to Rails, but I cannot find this feature!

Say you have a collection of invoices that includes an id, company name, and invoice total. For some reason, there are multiple companies with the same name. You want to create a 1xn matrix, where each row contains company data with a unique company name.

How can you group together companies with the same name, and add together their invoice totals. You do not care which id is saved to the row. Is the only way to use Group + Map?

e.g.

```
[1523, 'Red Roses Inc', 1300.00],
[4126, 'Blue Birds LLC', 110.00],
[846, 'Red Roses Inc', 400.00],
```

becomes

```
[1523, 'Red Roses Inc', 1700.00],
[846, 'Blue Birds LLC', 110.00],
```

Comment: Is your data in a table, or are you dealing with an array of arrays (perhaps drawn from a file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the company and invoice in one table for example your model is Invoice

```
Invoice.group(:company_name).sum(:total)

# sample implementation how to get data and print the result

data_result = Invoice.group(:company_name).sum(:total) 

data_result.each do |v|
  puts "company #{v[0]} total number #{v[1]}"
end

# this will print
# company Red Roses Inc total number 1700
# company Blue Birds LLC total number 110
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return a single number?